# How do I add a vertical line separating the two columns?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to be able to separate the two columns by a vertical line:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>some text here </p>
     </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>some more text here</p>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you fix your code example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use css `border-right:1px solid black` to achieve this. demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/35/

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 border-right">
            <p>some text here </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>some more text here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.border-right {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: This will work when the columns are of the same size. If you need css that will show a border based on which column is longer, please see my answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Must Open in Full Page to See Borders!

Added media width clauses in the CSS so there isn't any nasty borders on the mobile-friendly side of things. Hope this helps! This will resize to the length of the longest column. Tested on .col-md-4 and .col-md-6 and my assumption is it is compatible with the rest. No guarantees though.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzack5020/ooxn0vsr)

```css
.row {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cols {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media(min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-4:not(:first-child), 
  .col-md-6:not(:first-child) {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
  }
  .col-md-4:not(:last-child),
  .col-md-6:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    margin-right: -1px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <h1>
    .col-md-6
  </h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-6 cols">
      <p>Enter some text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 cols">
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <h1>
    .col-md-4
  </h1>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-4 cols">
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 cols">
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cols col-md-4 cols">
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be the perfect answer.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with previous, but I want to add one more solution.

You can use columns property and if you do that, there is a column-rule option, which adds a line perfectly between columns. [Here](https://kolosek.com/css-columns/) you can read and see on examples what I meant.